# how to affect css style on jQuery .live elements on page load

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-selectors, event-handling, pageload

Hey everybody.
I have some divs on a page being created as a result of a `json/ajax` call. At first they wouldnt trigger the jQuery functions, then I learned about `.live()` which solved my problem.

But now I want to do a little animating everytime the page loads. (or changes rather since im doing it through json).
Can anyone please tell me how to do something like this for example, but instead of "`click`" , using something like "`onload`" or "`load`"?

```
$('.thumbnail_area').live("click",function(){
    $(this).children().css('background-color', 'red')
});
```

Im just using this as a simple example. This works fine when clicked, but how can I get it to do this everytime the divs load. The end goal is to have them fadeIn one at a time.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a generic `onload()` jQuery function. You'll have to use the callback function for the AJAX request, as you can see here:

> jQuery.post( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ], [ dataType ] )

The `[ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ]` chunk says that you can place a function on there with those optional variables, like so:

```
jQuery.post('foo.php', $('#foo_form').serialize(), function(data)
{
  // I get called when the AJAX request finishes, so do your animating within me.
});
```

---

`.getJSON()` functions the same way:

```
jQuery.getJSON('foo.php', 'foobar', function(data)
{
  $('.thumbnail_area').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

If you are using jQuery (and not jQuery UI), you'll need to include a color plugin, [like this one](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/), in order to animate the colors of elements.

Comment: hey guys thanks for getting back so fast. Maybe I shouldnt have said I was using Ajax. Im using getJSON so maybe that makes a huge difference. Heres the site im working on.

Comment: damn how the hell do you make a new line in this damn thing? Heres the site im working on. http://www.webnamehere.com/johns_site/home.php. Lets say on load i want all the thumb backgrounds to change red. right now it only works when clicked. Also if this helps, at the start of the page, the thumbs are generated with php, then after a menu button is clicked, its through jetJSON. Which is why i need the .live().

Comment: You can't use newlines in comments. If you do, the system just deletes them. Anyways, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a "result" function used as a callback. Can't you simply ".hide()" the div with the id "id='" + result[i].bridge +"'" and then use the fadeIn function? Something like that right after the .append() function:

```
        $('#'+result[i].bridge).hide();
        $('#'+result[i].bridge).fadeIn();
```

Oh and nothing to do with the javascript of jQuery but you should never use numbers as IDs since it causes W3C validation errors. You could call them something like "id='newdiv_"++result[i].bridge+"'" and then get the id value by splitting the "_" char.

```
var sId = $(somediv).attr('id');
var actualID = sId.split('_')[1];
```

Comment: hey everybody. Thanks so much for all your help. I realize now i was going about the whole thing the wrong way. I was dynamically creating and appending divs, then trying to affect their css after. 

When I actually needed to put all my changes in the getJSON file. Otherwise Any changes I was making would take place, but then instantly change back when the new divs were appended. 

Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

hey everybody. Thanks so much for all your help. I realize now i was going about the whole thing the wrong way. I was dynamically creating and appending divs, then trying to affect their css after.

When I actually needed to put all my changes in the getJSON file. Otherwise Any changes I was making would take place, but then instantly change back when the new divs were appended.

Thanks again for all your help.